# Include node_modules to azure deployment

Tags: asp.net, azure, deployment, node-modules

With VS 2015 and project.json based applications, to include node_modules in deployments to Azure I would add

```
"publishOptions": {
    "include": [
        "node_modules",
        "wwwroot",
        "**/*.cshtml",
        "appsettings.json",
        "web.config"
    ]
},
```

How can I achieve the same with the new .csproj based applications?

More in general, is there a guide to migrating all the options from project.json to the new project format? I couldn't find anything useful...